# MATLAB - Rotating an equilateral triangle around its centre point

Tags: matlab, rotation

I am new to MATLAB, but have worked with javascript and other programming languages.

I am writing a MATLAB program that will generate an equilateral triangle given the side length, an x coordinate, a y coordinate and an angle of rotation. It is working as intended except for the rotations.
I am using a rotation matrix to rotate the triangle. This works, except it rotates around the origin instead of rotating on the spot. (see below example).

90 degree Rotations Example

[image]

In order to rotate it on the spot I think I need to calculate the centre of the triangle and then rotate around that(somehow). I am not sure how to do this or if there is an easier/better way to do this. I did see there is a rotate function, but from what I have seen, it is for spherical space, not Cartesian planes.

Code is below, sorry for the mess:

```
function [ side, coord1,coord2 ] = equilateral(side, x,y, rotation)
%EQUILATERAL- given a side length and x,y, coordinates as inputs, the
%function plots an equilateral triangle an angle of rotation can be
%given as an input as well. This will rotate the trianlge around the x
%and y coordinates given.

%rotation argument is not required. If not given, angle is 0
if(exist('rotation','var'))
   angle = rotation;
else 
    angle = 0;
end

%rotation matrix
R = [cos(angle), -sin(angle); sin(angle), cos(angle)];
%Make the axis equal so the triangles look equilateral
axis equal;
%max horizontal x coordinate
x2 = x + side;
%max horiontal y coordinate (equal to original y coordinate)
y2 = y;
%height of the triangle at midpoint (perpendicular height)
h = side*sin(pi/3) + y;
%coordinates of midpoint/top vertice
mid = [x2-(0.5*side), h];
%min coordinates
coord1 = [x,y];
%max coordinates
coord2 = [x2,y2];

if (angle > 0)
    coord1 = coord1*R;
    coord2 = coord2*R;
    mid = mid*R;

end

%plot the base of the triangle
plot(linspace(coord1(1),coord2(1)), linspace(coord1(2),coord2(2)));
hold on
%plot the first side from inital coords to midpoint
plot(linspace(coord1(1),mid(1)), linspace(coord1(2),mid(2)));
%plot second side from mid point to max coords
plot(linspace(mid(1),coord2(1)), linspace(mid(2),coord2(2)));
end
```

I am open to any suggestions for improvements to the code/help to clean it up as well as help with the rotation issues. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rotation` matrix

```
[cos(theta), -sin(theta)
 sin(theta), cos(theta)]
```

rotates a set of points of an angle `theta` about the origin of the axes.

In order to rotate a point around a given point, you have to:

-`shift` your points so that the rotatioin point concides with the origin of the axes
- rotate the point using the rotation matrix
- shift back your points

The following  code is a modified version of your function in which the proposed approach has been implemented.

In the code I've set the rotation point as the centre of gravity

```
XR=x+side/2
YR=y+h*.3
```

nevertheless, you can compute them in a different way.

```
function [ side, coord1,coord2 ] = equilateral(side, x,y, rotation)
%EQUILATERAL- given a side length and x,y, coordinates as inputs, the
%function plots an equilateral triangle an angle of rotation can be
%given as an input as well. This will rotate the trianlge around the x
%and y coordinates given.

%rotation argument is not required. If not given, angle is 0
if(exist('rotation','var'))
%   angle = rotation;
% Convert the angle from deg to rad
   angle = rotation*pi/180;
else 
    angle = 0;
end

%rotation matrix
R = [cos(angle), -sin(angle); sin(angle), cos(angle)];
%Make the axis equal so the triangles look equilateral
axis equal;
%max horizontal x coordinate
x2 = x + side;
%max horiontal y coordinate (equal to original y coordinate)
y2 = y;
%height of the triangle at midpoint (perpendicular height)
h = side*sin(pi/3) + y;
%coordinates of midpoint/top vertice
mid = [x2-(0.5*side), h];
%min coordinates
coord1 = [x,y];
%max coordinates
coord2 = [x2,y2];
plot([coord1(1) coord2(1) mid(1) coord1(1)],[coord1(2) coord2(2) mid(2) coord1(2)],'r')
hold on
%
% Define the coord of the point aroud with to turn
%
XR=x+side/2
YR=y+h*.3
plot(XR,YR,'o','markerfacecolor','k','markeredgecolor','k')

if (angle > 0)
%     coord1 = coord1*R;
%     coord2 = coord2*R;
%     mid = mid*R;
% Shift the triangle so that the rotation point coincides with the origin
% of the axes
    r_coord1 = (coord1-[XR YR])*R+[XR YR];
    r_coord2 = (coord2-[XR YR])*R+[XR YR];
    r_mid = (mid-[XR YR])*R+[XR YR];
%
% Plot the rotated triangle
plot([r_coord1(1) r_coord2(1) r_mid(1) r_coord1(1)],[r_coord1(2) r_coord2(2) r_mid(2) r_coord1(2)],'r')
end

% % % 
% % % %plot the base of the triangle
% % % plot(linspace(coord1(1),coord2(1)), linspace(coord1(2),coord2(2)));
% % % hold on
% % % %plot the first side from inital coords to midpoint
% % % plot(linspace(coord1(1),mid(1)), linspace(coord1(2),mid(2)));
% % % %plot second side from mid point to max coords
% % % plot(linspace(mid(1),coord2(1)), linspace(mid(2),coord2(2)));
end
```

I've also made a couple of additional modification:

- I've added a conversion of the input angle from `deg` to `rad`; you can discard it if you assume the input is already in `rad`
- I've updated the way to plot the triangle.

As a suggestion, you can use [nargin](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html) to thest the number of input to your function and [varargin](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) to inspect them instead of testing in they exist.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Qapla'